# Creating a command that replaces the word under the cursor with another one?

Tags: vim

I want to create a command that replaces the word under the cursor by another one, say I have the word `have` under my cursor and it replaces it with the word `had` and vice versa. How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 8):

This could easily be accomplished by `ciw` and then entering the word that you would like to replace it with. Assuming that you want to replace words with different values.

Another solution is you could use a plugin like [switch.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4172). You would have to define the words/regular expressions you would want to replace.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually want to do this with longer words, then this method may help.  First, position the cursor on the word "had" and use `yiw` to yank (copy) it into the `@0` register (and also the unnamed register, but we are about to overwrite that).  Then move the cursor to "have" and use `ciw<C-R>0<Esc>` to replace it with the yanked word.

Do not type `<C-R>` as five characters:  I mean hold down the CTRL key and type <kbd>r</kbd>.  Similarly, `<Esc>` means the escape key.  Do type each as five characters if you want to make a map out of it, for example

```
:nmap <F2> ciw<C-R>0<Esc>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace all occurrences of the word under the cursor, you can add this into your _vimrc:

```
" search and replace all occurrences of word under cursor
:nnoremap <C-h> :%s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>/
:inoremap <C-h> <ESC>:%s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>/
```

Usage of this:

1) Press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>** (under the cursor is the word "have"), and Vim will enter this in the command line:

```
:%s/\<have\>/
```

2) Now just complete the replacing statement:

```
:%s/\<have\>/had/g
```

3) And press **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**...

Answer (score 0):

The [SwapIt - Extensible keyword swapper](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2294) allows you to configure sets of words (e.g. `have` and `had`) and toggle them via `<C-a>` / `<C-x>` mappings.